# enable entry widget by clicking on button

Tags: python, string, tkinter, pycharm, floating

in this code below i need to make a button if clicked use the entered number by user in entry widget (innenleiter)   and if not, then use the variable formula and proceed.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import scipy.special as scs
import scipy.optimize as sco
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def button_clear():
    eps_r_Entry.delete(0, END)
    impedanz_Entry.delete(0, END)
    aussenleiter_Entry.delete(0, END)
    innenleiter_Entry.delete(0, END)

def result_function():
    c0 = 299792458
    m0 = 4 * np.pi * 1e-7
    e0 = 1 / (m0 * c0 ** 2)
    z0 = np.sqrt(m0 / e0)

    zl = float(impedanz_Var.get())
    eps_r = float(eps_r_Var.get())
    aus_d = float(aussenleiter_Var.get())

 
    # in_d = float(innenleiter_Var.get())

    ''''
    here i need a button if clicked use the number entered in Entry widget (innenleiter) 
    if not, take this variable and proceed  (in_d = aus_d / (np.e ** (zl * 2 * np.pi * 
    np.sqrt(eps_r) / z0))
    '''
    in_d = aus_d / (np.e ** (zl * 2 * np.pi * np.sqrt(eps_r) / z0))

   
    r1 = np.sqrt(eps_r) * aus_d / 2
    r = np.sqrt(eps_r) * in_d / 2
    a = r1 / r
    z = z0 / (2 * np.pi * np.sqrt(eps_r)) * np.log(aus_d / in_d)

    def wav_num(x):
        return ((scs.jn(0, x*a) - scs.jn(2, x*a)) * (scs.yn(0, x) - scs.yn(2, x))
                - (scs.yn(0, x*a) - scs.yn(2, x*a)) * (scs.jn(0, x) - scs.jn(2, x)))
    x = np.arange(0.1, 1.0, 0.01)
    test = wav_num(x)
    etsi = sco.brentq(wav_num, 0.1, 1.0)
    f_g = etsi * (a + 1) / (2 * np.pi * np.sqrt(m0 * e0) * (r1 + r) * 1e-3) / 1e9

    result = round(f_g, 2)
    result1 = round(z, 2)
    result2 = round(in_d, 2)

    Result_label.config(text='f_g :  ' + str(result))
    Result_label1.config(text='impedanz  :  ' + str(result1))
    Result_label2.config(text='innenleiter D/O :  ' + str(result2))

    # fig = plt.figure(1)
    plt.close()
    plt.figure(1)
    plt.plot(x, test)
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.savefig("result.png", dpi=70)

    logo = Image.open('result.png')
    logo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(logo)
    logo_label = tk.Label(image=logo)
    logo_label.image = logo
    logo_label.grid(row=13, column=8, columnspan=4)

    return logo

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Coax TE Mode")
root.geometry("1400x1080")
root.config(background="#145")
var = DoubleVar()

# generate the window
title = Label(root, text="Coax TE Mode", font=('Helvetica', 22), bg="#145", fg="white")
title.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=20, pady=20)
leerZeile = Label(root, text="", bg="#145", fg="#145")
leerZeile.grid(row=1, column=1)
leerZeile = Label(root, text="", bg="#145", fg="#145")
leerZeile.grid(row=2, column=1)

# Impedanz = Zl (in die gleichung als Z gezeichnet)
impedanz_Label = Label(root, text="Impedanz", font=12, bg="#145", fg="white")
impedanz_Label.grid(row=6, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
impedanz_Var = DoubleVar()
impedanz_Entry = Entry(root, textvariable=impedanz_Var, width=32, borderwidth=5, )
impedanz_Entry.grid(row=6, column=1, columnspan=4, padx=10, pady=10)

# Innenleiter = d (in die gleichung als d gezeigt)
innenleiter_Label = Label(root, text="Innenleiter", font=12, bg="#145", fg="white")
innenleiter_Label.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
innenleiter_Var = DoubleVar()
innenleiter_Entry = Entry(root, textvariable=innenleiter_Var, width=32, borderwidth=5)
innenleiter_Entry.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=4, padx=10, pady=10)

# Aussenleiter = D (in die gleichung als D gezeigt)
aussenleiter_Label = Label(root, text="Außenleiter", font=12, bg="#145", fg="white")
aussenleiter_Label.grid(row=5, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
aussenleiter_Var = DoubleVar()
aussenleiter_Entry = Entry(root, textvariable=aussenleiter_Var, width=32, borderwidth=5)
aussenleiter_Entry.grid(row=5, column=1, columnspan=4, padx=10, pady=10)

# eps_r = in die gleichung als Permittivity dry air 1.000594
eps_r_Label = Label(root, text="eps_r", font=12, bg="#145", fg="white")
eps_r_Label.grid(row=7, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
eps_r_Var = DoubleVar()
eps_r_Entry = Entry(root, textvariable=eps_r_Var, width=32, borderwidth=5)
eps_r_Entry.grid(row=7, column=1, columnspan=4, padx=10, pady=10)

# Result btn
Result_btn = Button(command=result_function, text="Result", bg="#145", fg="white", font=12)
Result_btn.grid(row=8, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)

# Show Result tkinter root window
Result_label = Label(root, text="", bg="#145", fg="white", font=14)
Result_label.grid(row=10, column=2, columnspan=20, padx=2, pady=2)

Result_label1 = Label(root, text="", bg="#145", fg="white", font=14)
Result_label1.grid(row=11, column=2, columnspan=20, padx=2, pady=2)

Result_label2 = Label(root, text="", bg="#145", fg="white", font=14)
Result_label2.grid(row=12, column=2, columnspan=20, padx=2, pady=2)

# clear btn soll entry fields räumen
plt_btn = Button(text="clear", command=button_clear, bg="#145", fg="white", font=12)
plt_btn.grid(row=8, column=3, padx=10, pady=10)

# Exit
exit_btn = Button(root, text="Exit", bg="#145", fg="white", font=12, command=root.quit)
exit_btn.grid(row=8, column=4, padx=10, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please don't put code in the comment section. You can [edit] your original question if you need to add more details. Also, if the question is about enabling an entry widget with a button, we don't need much more than an entry, a button, and enough code to tie them together.

Comment: You can add a `Checkbutton` widget.  If it is checked, use value in `innenleiter_Var`, otherwise use the calculated value.

Answer (score 0):

So this seems like a simple issue but let me know if I misunderstood. What you want to do is disable and enable a text widget. To do this you would use `some_text_widget.config(state="enabled")` to enable the widget and/or `some_text_widget.config(state="disabled")`. Does this work for you?